# Multiclass Classification in Caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

In the caret package, which ensemble models can be used for multi class classification?
 Also on trying some of the functions mentioned in http://topepo.github.io/caret/Ensemble_Model.html it is giving:

> **Not in caret's built-in library**.

There are no suggestions of relevant packages for many functions on Google either. Could anyone kindly help me out with both these questions?

Answer (score 5):

Most of them can (assuming that they are not solely regression models). We've listed the exclusions [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Two_Class_Only.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) you can see an overview that also lists packages needed.

Comment: And how about knowing which ones work for multiclass classification also?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a list on that and I do not know all the methods available in caret or what they are capable of.